# How do I add my script and desktop file so it's configurable as a preferred application?

Tags: cinnamon, update-alternatives

I'm trying to set up a URL router script that looks at urls and opens them with a different browser instance (firefox profile in my case) depending on the result of pattern matching performed against the url.

I've made myself a desktop file, and installed it with `desktop-file-install` (details below).  I'd expect that it should be visible in the main menu, and as an option when running `cinnamon-settings default` (which appears "Preferred Applications" in the main menu.  Neither of these things happens.

`cinnamon-settings default`, `update-alternatives` and `xdg-settings` each has it's own list of options.  My script doesn't appear in any of them.  Which ones matter?  How do I registered my script or desktop file as an available alternative for use by these systems?

My Desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Url Router
Comment=Route to browser instances based on URL
# TryExec=url-router
Exec=url-router %u
# X-MultipleArgs=false
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https
Icon=firefox
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
# StartupWMClass=Firefox-esr
```

... which I've installed like so:

```bsh
    desktop-file-install --dir=$HOME/.local/share/applications/ \
      --mode=755 \
      --rebuild-mime-info-cache \
      url-router.desktop
```

Comment: Please provide OS & release details

Comment: `NoDisplay=true` will cause the launcher *not* to be shown in the main menu, so you should not expect that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that `url-router` is in my ~/bin folder, but when launching desktop files, that isn't in my `$PATH`, which I set from `.bashrc`.

Also, @vanadium's comment about `NoDisplay=true` is important for display in the Main Menu, though not for the Preferred Applications, which was my main concern.

Comment: How does that answer the question on how to include the launcher in the drop down of "Preferred applications"?

Comment: @vanadium `url-router` appeared there when I entered a full path into Exec in the desktop file.

Comment: @vanadium rebuildingthe mime info cache is presumably also an important step, but I was already doing that with an option to `desktop-file-install`

Comment: Thank makes a lot of sense. It would be fine to include this background in your answer to clarify everything for future users.